# Jar library vs Android Library. Which is the difference?

Tags: java, android, jar, android-library

I have a doubt :
Jar library vs Android Library

Which is the difference ?

In jar library I can't use Android's methods, but I can only use java's functions; right ? (for example I can't use the android's method for Json)

**EDIT :** *I have read the below answer and I have understood that I can use Android SDK inside the JAR file.
The question is : 
How can I use method from Android SDK in a JAR file ?*

Thus if I want to use a library's function to write on my webview, I think is better that I use the Android Library. Is it Right or I commit some mistake in my reasoning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which is the difference ?

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules), with emphasis added:

> An Android library module is a development module that holds shared Android source code **and resources**.

An Android library module (formerly known as an Android library project) also supports packaging assets, NDK libraries, and manifest entries, whereas a plain JAR does not.

> In jar library I can't use Android's methods, but I can only use java's functions; right ?

No, you can create a JAR that uses classes and methods from the Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answer :) 
I edit the question, because after you answer I have another question :
How can I use method from Android SDK in a JAR file ?

Comment: @aeroxr1: That depends a lot on your development toolchain. Basically you want to create a regular Android project/library module/whatever, one that is set up to compile against the Android SDK. You avoid using resources and create a JAR out of the results. So, most of my CWAC libraries, like [CWAC-RichTextUtils](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-richtextutils), consist of an Android library module, and I have a Gradle task that can create a JAR out of the results that I publish for Eclipse users.

Comment: thanks for your time :) The topic is much complex for me :( When you have the time, can you post to me some link or guide or book's title where is been explained this argument ? Thanks ! Very thanks :)